# How to open local documents directly in Google Docs?

Tags: google-docs

I read [this article](http://lifehacker.com/5696869/launch-new-google-documents-from-shortcuts-or-hotkeys) on Lifehacker on how to make a shortcut to open an empty Google Doc right from the desktop.

I would like to be able to open my file browser and just click on a document and have it open/import directly into Google Docs, basically "forcing" it to act like a local application. Maybe something like a `&action=opendoc&docname=foo` or something.

Does something like this exist?

<sub>I know how to mass upload documents into Google Docs, what I'm hoping for is a more transparent way of using the documents on my desktop with Google Docs.</sub>

Comment: same here. I want to open files from the File Explorer and that it opens in a browser as a Google Docs or Google Presentation or Sheets document.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because "Google Docs" has changed a lot since this question was posted. The file storage / manager and the file editor are different apps and the old APIs were deprecated.

Comment: Related questions from this site: [Open local documents with Google Docs (offline)](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/111940/88163) (from 2017), Related questions from [su]: [How to open doc, ppt, or xls files with Google Drive with double clicks from my desktop?](https://superuser.com/q/1038790/152004) (from 2016), [How to open a local office file stored in Google Drive (docs, sheets etc.) directly?](https://superuser.com/q/1754475/152004) (from 2023)