# Open local documents with Google Docs (offline)

Tags: google-docs, offline

Google Docs can be used offline if you install the Chrome add on. Moreover, I can upload local documents to Google Drive and work with them in Google Docs.

Now suppose that I am offline and I have a local document in my laptop.

Can I get it open on Google Docs (while being offline)?

Answer (score 1):

Open local files and convert them to Google Docs editors format it's not supported.

From [Use Google Drive files offline](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012?hl=en)

> If you aren't connected to a Wi-Fi or mobile network, you can still
>   view and edit files, including:
>
> - Google Docs
> - Google Sheets
> - Google Slides

Answer (score 0):

Google Docs only supports offline access after you've enabled it on your Google Drive account; and it's only supported with the Google Docs Offline extension in the Google Chrome browser.

See https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375012?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en for information about enabling and setting up offline access.

Comment: I have offline access enabled and working perfectly. This question is about opening *local* files with Google Docs, while being offline.